# Eloquent Collections, how to modify the data of each registry contained in results?

Tags: php, laravel-5, collections, eloquent

I have the following situation, Im trying to modify the price of products displayed in a platform.

**Everything works ok for only 1 product (eg: product view) but I dont know what I have to do in order to modify the price of each product in an eloquent collection.**

this is the code in my app:

ProductRepository.php:

```
public function CalcPrice($product){
    $x = $product->price; //eg 5
    $y = 4;
    $amount= $x + $y;
    return $amount;
}
```

For the details view of each product inside ProductController I have the following code and everything works perfect:

```
public function details($id){
  $product = $this->product->getProductById($id);
  $productprice = $this->product->getCalcPrice($product = $product);
  return view('products.view',compact('product','productprice'))
}
```

On the other hand, my idea is to use the code contained in ProductRepository.php function CalcPrice in a collection.

My main doubt is what do I have to do, because in a collection probably I can have a variable $category in order to retrieve all products in a category, but I will not have a variable for each $product (for eg: a $productid like in details).

What can I do in order to eg:

> modify each product price contained in a collection of a category
>   using CalcPrice function code?

eg: of code:
productrepository.php

```
public function AllProductsInCategory($catid)
    {
        return App\Product::where('categoryid', $catid)
        ->get();
}
```

but each product displaying their ($product->price + 4) as CalcPrice performs. thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining an attribute accessor on model and append it to model. This way it would be available for you on each instance like its other attributes. 
As Taylor Otwell mentioned [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/112#issuecomment-12530987), "This is intentional and for performance reasons." However there is an easy way to achieve this, say you have model named `Product`;

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    protected $appends = array('calc_price');

    public function getCalcPriceAttribute()
    {
       //if you want to call your method for some reason  
       return $this->getCalcPrice($this);
       // Otherwise more clean way would be something like this
       // return $this->price + 4 // un-comment if you don't want to call getCalcPrice() method
    }
}
```

Now you can access calculated price on each `$product` by simply calling `$product->calc_price`.

Comment: yes it was attribute option in model de correct choice. thank you!